Some property of the greatest prime factor
Let $n$ be a positive integer $\geq 2$ et denote by $ P^{+}(n)$ the greatest prime factor of $n$ my question is as follows:
If $a$ and $b$ are two numbers, is there any method to express or to bound $P^{+}(a×n+b)$ in terms of $P^{+}(n)$?

For every pair of nonzero integers $a,b$ there is no function $f=f_{a,b}:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ such that $P(an+b)\le f(P(n))$. Otherwise, $P(2^ka+b)\le f(2)$, but $P(2^ka+b)$ is unbounded for $k\ge1$ (see discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626903/)

Take nonzero integers $a,b$. If $f=f_{a,b}:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $P(an+b)\ge f(P(n))$, then there is some $C$ such that $f(p)\le C$ for infinitely many primes $p$. Namely, there are $N\ge2$ and infinitely many $k$ such that $N^k\equiv b\pmod a$ (take $N=|a|r+b$ for fixed large enough $r$ and $k\equiv1\pmod{\varphi(a)}$). Then $C=P(N)=P(N^k)\ge f(P((N^k-b)/a))$, where $P((N^k-b)/a)$ is unbounded
